# Paypal billing plan description?

Tags: paypal

I want to do the following in paypal rest! api billing plan:

[image]

the description in the left, how do i do this in php rest api when it comes to billing plan?

For example, if it was just one ordinary item, i did this with the following code:

```
 $item = new Item();

 $item->setQuantity('1');
 $item->setName('benny');
 $item->setPrice('7.41');
 $item->setCurrency('USD');
 $item->setSku('blah');
 // //var_dump($item);

 $items = new ItemList();
 $items->addItem($item);
 ...

 $transaction->setItemList($items);
```

I don't see anything similar when it comes to the plans api:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#billing-plans-and-agreements

This is what i get when i do an agreement: (only description but i want items to be here too, just like the prev example)

[image]

Comment: Support for billing plans and agreements is coming to the PHP sdk soon, its being actively worked on right now. This is Avi from PayPal.

Comment: Billing Plans are now available on the php sdk https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/releases/tag/v0.14.0

Comment: @AviDas, that does not really answer the question. It does not look like you can have a list of items in a plan, only a description (of which the maximum size is not defined in the API documentation!)

Comment: Bump, any news about this one, @AviDas?

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/149